# Calculate distance between camera and object

Tags: geometry, computer-vision

I have a camera and a blank cardboard box standing upright with measurements of 30cm x 30cm. I want to be able for the camera to capture the entire area of the cardboard, how far does the camera need to be to capture the entire 30cm x 30cm front surface?

The camera is 640 x480  and has 160 degree viewing angle

Comment: That depends on what lenses you have in the camera. The best way to find an answer is just to try it out, if that that is an option at all.

Comment: Magnification of  lenses? If you please? @donmalty

Comment: Just made an edit. Camera is 640 x480 and has 160 degree viewing angle. Im not sure about the magnification of lense

Comment: $160^\circ$ viewing angle is the one thing we need. Do you know basic trigonometry?